# PowerShell Graph SDK with the Complex Parameter Properties Syntax

Tags: powershell, syntax, sdk

I'm trying to use the PowerShell Graph SDK with the Complex Parameter Properties, as the few simple parameters don't produce the results I need.

Using `Get-MgReportEmailActivityUserDetail -Period = "D30" -OutFile = "test.csv"`, works as expected, however I need to get the stats for a range (i.e. `startDateTime = "12/01/2023" endDateTime = "12/31/2023"`.

I've created the hash table for the InputObject, but no matter the format, it throws an error.

There is very little documentation on the syntax using COMPLEX PARAMETER PROPERTIES as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.reports/get-mgreportemailactivityuserdetail?view=graph-powershell-1.0

Here is a sample of what I'm trying:

```
$startDateTime = get-date 12/01/2023
$endDateTime = Get-Date 12/31/2023

$dateTimeHash = @{
        startDateTime = $startDateTime
        endDateTime = $endDateTime
        }

Get-MgReportEmailActivityUserDetail @dateTimeHash -OutFile "test.csv"
```

```
Get-MgReportEmailActivityUserDetail : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'startDateTime'.
At line:1 char:37
+ Get-MgReportEmailActivityUserDetail @dateTimeHash -OutFile "test.csv"
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-MgReportEmailActivityUserDetail], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Get-MgReportEmailActivityUserDetail
```

or another command using -InputObject parameter:

```
Get-MgReportEmailActivityUserDetail -InputObject $dateTimeHash -OutFile "Test.csv"
```

```
Get-MgReportEmailActivityUserDetail : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-MgReportEmailActivityUserDetail -InputObject $dateTimeHash -OutFi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-MgReportEmailActivityUserDetail], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Get-MgReportEmailActivityUserDetail
```

Comment: Your last attempt is correct, but I think the cmdlet itself might be broken - defining two non-default parameter sets with identically named and typed parameters would explain the `AmbiguousParameterSet` error you're seeing. Time to file a bug report with Microsoft :)